# pandas dataframe to latex table according to variable value

Tags: python, pandas, latex, dataframe

I have a large dataframe

```
In [25]: df
Out[25]: 
    FN   FP   TN  TP                     data method
0    0    0  980  20  A p=1000 n=1000 SNR=0.5     HF
1    0    0  980  20  A p=1000 n=1000 SNR=0.5     HM
2   16    0  980   4  A p=1000 n=1000 SNR=0.5  HMP80
3   18    0  980   2  A p=1000 n=1000 SNR=0.5  HMP90
4    0    0  980  20  A p=1000 n=1000 SNR=0.5   LP70
5    0    0  980  20  A p=1000 n=1000 SNR=0.5   LP85
6    0    0  980  20  A p=1000 n=1000 SNR=0.5    lCV
7    0   58  922  20   C p=1000 n=200 SNR=0.5     HF
8    0   58  922  20   C p=1000 n=200 SNR=0.5     HM
9   17   13  967   3   C p=1000 n=200 SNR=0.5  HMP80
10  19    7  973   1   C p=1000 n=200 SNR=0.5  HMP90
11   0   58  922  20   C p=1000 n=200 SNR=0.5   LP70
12   0   58  922  20   C p=1000 n=200 SNR=0.5   LP85
13   0   58  922  20   C p=1000 n=200 SNR=0.5    lCV
14   0    0  980  20  B p=1000 n=1000 SNR=0.5     HF
15   0    0  980  20  B p=1000 n=1000 SNR=0.5     HM
```

I would like to obtain a latex table where:

1 - method is the rows name.

2 -  the table is divided in blocks according to the value of data. Data should be the header of each block.

3 - I need 4 blocks for each row. (to fit it in the page)

4 -  the blocks have to be alphabetically ordered according to the value of data.

I have tried to use matrix2table library but it seems that a lot of preprocessing work is required. 
Is there any easy way to solve this problem? 
I am not very familiar with pandas so maybe there are some useful tricks.

EDIT :
This is how the output should look like in a latex document.

```
An example of output 
      |TP     FP    TN     FN | TP   FP   TN   FN |   .... Other 2 blocks 
method| A p=1000 n=1000   data| A p=1000 n=100    |
HF    | 20    0     980     0 | 3     2    1    1 |
HM    | 20    0     980     0 | 2     5    62   3 |
...
...
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | B p=1000 n =100        |  B=1000 n=200      | ..........
HF  | 2      3       4     5 |  32   43    24   24| ..........
HM  | 34     532     23    3 |  23    3    23   23| ..........
...
```

Comment: Can you give an example of your desired output (even if it's just a couple of rows).

Comment: Done. Let me know if it is still not clear

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably have to play around with formatting on the LaTeX that is output, but does something like this help?  Your data doesn't exactly match your output, so I made a couple assumed changes.

```
In [362]: df
Out[362]: 
    FN  FP   TN  TP                     data method
0    0   0  980  20  A p=1000 n=1000 SNR=0.5     HF
1    0   0  980  20  A p=1000 n=1000 SNR=0.5     HM
2   16   0  980   4  A p=1000 n=1000 SNR=0.5  HMP80
3    0  58  922  20   C p=1000 n=200 SNR=0.5     HF
4    0  58  922  20   C p=1000 n=200 SNR=0.5     HM
5   17  13  967   3   C p=1000 n=200 SNR=0.5  HMP80
6    0   0  980  20  B p=1000 n=1000 SNR=0.5     HF
7    0   0  980  20  B p=1000 n=1000 SNR=0.5     HM
8    0   0  980  20   A p=1000 n=100 SNR=0.5     HF
9    0   0  980  20   A p=1000 n=100 SNR=0.5     HM
10  16   0  980   4   A p=1000 n=100 SNR=0.5  HMP80
11   0  58  922  20   C p=1000 n=100 SNR=0.5     HF
12   0  58  922  20   C p=1000 n=100 SNR=0.5     HM
13  17  13  967   3   C p=1000 n=100 SNR=0.5  HMP80
14   0   0  980  20   B p=1000 n=100 SNR=0.5     HF
15   0   0  980  20   B p=1000 n=100 SNR=0.5     HM

In [363]: df['data_group'] = df['data'].str.slice(0,1)
```

Once you have a column identifying each row group, the code below (using pandas groupby) pivots the 'data' rows into columns and writes section to a text file in LaTeX format.

```
In [377]: with open('latex_table.txt', 'w') as f:
     ...:     header = True
     ...:     for _, df_gb in df.groupby('data_group'):
     ...:         df_gb = df_gb.drop('data_group', axis=1)
     ...:         df_gb = df_gb.pivot(index='method', columns='data')
     ...:         df_gb.columns = df_gb.columns.sortlevel(1)[0]
     ...:         df_gb.to_latex(f, header=header)
```

Comment: This is a very good answer but is there any way to do not print the value data on each column but only as header? for the 4 columns TP, FP, ...?